# AWS Lex chatbot not logging utterances (both missed and detected utterances)

Tags: chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

One of our AWS bots is not logging detected and missed utterances. Where as all the new bots created in the same account are logging missed utterances in Monitoring -> Utterances section. I have checked the configuration of all the bots and it is all same.
In Monitoring -> Monitoring Graphs, I can see the graph showing missed utterances. I am failing to understand why the utterances (both missed and detected) is not appearing in the Monitoring > Utterances section. I know we need to wait 24 hours for them to appear. But it is not appearing at all even after 2 days. So if you can suggest some reasons for this, I will try to look into it.
I have made the aliases point to the latest version so no chance of utterances going to a wrong version. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utterance statistics are not generated under the following conditions:

- The childDirected field was set to true when the bot was created.
- You are using slot obfuscation with one or more slots.
- You opted out of participating in improving Amazon Lex.

And as you mentioned, need to wait ~24 hours for data to be processed:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-utterances.html